# parsing json that represents a network(graph)

Tags: json, graph

I have a json string that is a json-representation of a network(node, edge).

Below is the example.

{

"children": [

{

"score": "1",

"children": [

{

"score": "3",

"id": 3,

"label": "WORD"

},

{

"score": "3",

"label": "WORD"

}

],

"id": 2,

"label": "WORD"

},

{

"score": "1",

"children": [

{

"score": "3",

"id": 9,

"label": "WORD"

},

{

"score": "3",

"id": 12,

"label": "WORD"

}

],

"id": 8,

"label": "WORD"

}

],

"id": 1,

"label": "WORD"

}

Each "children" is a node and other properties are for each
node instance.

How can it be converted to a java object?

Basically it should be a list of Node instance.

For that purpose I may need a java class for a node like

```
Class Node 
{
   private int score;
   private int id;
   private String label;
   private List<Integer> childrenIdList;

   public Node()
   {}

   // setter and getter

}
```

Then I need to convert the json string to java objects using JSon simple or
GSon.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using GSon.

1) Create a node object with the help from the site

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

2) Node class(named as children)

```
package example;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Children {

@SerializedName("score")
@Expose
private String score;
@SerializedName("children")
@Expose
private List<Children> children = new ArrayList<Children>();
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("label")
@Expose
private String label;

/**
* 
* @return
* The score
*/
public String getScore() {
return score;
}

/**
* 
* @param score
* The score
*/
public void setScore(String score) {
this.score = score;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The children
*/
public List<Children> getChildren() {
return children;
}

/**
* 
* @param children
* The children
*/
public void setChildren(List<Children> children) {
this.children = children;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The label
*/
public String getLabel() {
return label;
}

/**
* 
* @param label
* The label
*/
public void setLabel(String label) {
this.label = label;
}

}
```

3) Recursively iterate

```
    public void parse(String json) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException, ParseException
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Children object = gson.fromJson(json, Children.class);   
        Iterator<Children> iter=object.getChildren().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            Children c=(Children)iter.next();
            if ( c.getChildren().size() > 0 )
            {
                System.out.println("current node(1):"+c.getLabel());
                viewChildren(c);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("top:"+c.getLabel());
            }
        }
    }

    public void viewChildren(Children _c)
    {
        Iterator<Children> iter=_c.getChildren().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            Children c=(Children)iter.next();
            if ( c.getChildren().size() > 0 )
            {
                System.out.println("current node(2):"+c.getLabel());
                viewChildren(c);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("inner:"+c.getLabel());
            }
        }
    }
```